# Using Faraday Middleware to cache responses from the GitHub API

Tags: ruby, caching, github, faraday

I'm trying to setup caching on starred repos, but I can't get faraday_http_cache nor faraday_middleway's response cache to work with Octokit.

```
Octokit.middleware = Faraday::Builder.new do |builder|
  builder.use Faraday::HttpCache # won't cache the private responses
  builder.use FaradayMiddleware:Caching @cache # fails to cache silently when using Marshal for caching
  builder.use Octokit::Response::RaiseError
  builder.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  # builder.response :logger
end
```

Not sure where to turn to cache starred repos.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `shared_cache: false`, so make the line `builder.use :http_cache, shared_cache: false`